# how to check user ip from db and enable/disable form textarea

Tags: php, mysql

i am having some trouble to figure this out.a user loging and its ip `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will be checked in from a database of multiple rows having multiple ip's.

```
id(Primary)    name    ip
1              abc     127.0.0.1,999.45.67.89
2              xyz     192.168.0.1,108.34.65.78
```

now if i logged in my ip 127.0.0.1 is present in 1st row.i have a form which fetch the above table.

```
<?php
$sql="select * from center_listt";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res) {
die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
} ?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table border="1">

                <table>
                  <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>IP Details</th>
                </tr>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{
?>
<tr >
        <td><?php echo $row['idr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip_details[]"><?php echo $row['ipdetails']; ?></textarea><br/></td>

         </tr>
```

so if my ip is found in the 1st row of the database or fetched-textarea i can only edit in that textarea.other textarea will be disabled.i dont know but to check the user-ip and then looping it through each rows from db and if ip found maybe a javascript to enable disable?

Comment: If these - 127.0.0.1,**999**.45.67.89 - are the actual IPs from your application, there might be something VERY wrong with your network settings.

Comment: i think its just an example that will relate with the question

Comment: Your database design is not good. You have to make a table with multiple rows and single IP's. (with maybe a timestamp or whatever information that you want). Because if a user moves alot, your row will get very large..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$sql="select * from center_listt WHERE ip LIKE '%" + $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] + "%'";
```

to select all rows contains current user's ip address.

Best regards,

Nebojsa